# How to optimize this algorithm using tail recursion?

Tags: javascript, depth-first-search, tail-recursion

I want to optimize this dfs with tail recursion,but i don't konw how to realize it, could any help me?

My first solution is the following code, i want modify it with tail recursion to get test case with 21

```
const tree = {
  val: 1,
  children: [
    { val: 2, children: [] },
    {
      val: 3,
      children: [
        { val: 4, children: [] },
        { val: 5, children: [] },
      ],
    },
    { val: 6, children: [] },
  ],
};


function dfs(root) {
  if (root.children && root.children.length > 0) {
    let tmp = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < root.children.length; i++) {
      tmp += dfs(root.children[i]);
    }
    return (tmp += root.val);
  } else {
    return root.val;
  }
}

let ret = 0;
console.log("ret: ", dfs(tree));//get 21 this case
```

Comment: Most JavaScript engines don’t have tail call elimination, so note that this won’t be an optimization. Also, DFS isn’t really suited to tail calls – you may as well just use an array as a stack with a loop if that’s what you were going to do with tail recursion.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

DFS doesn't play nicely with tail recursion. You can hack around that, for example, by passing an explicit list of "nodes-to-visit", as in

```js
function sum(todo, total=0) {
    if (todo.length === 0)
        return total

    let [node, ...rest] = todo
    return sum([...rest, ...node.children], total + node.val)
}

//

const tree = {
    val: 1,
    children: [
        { val: 2, children: [] },
        {
            val: 3,
            children: [
                { val: 4, children: [] },
                { val: 5, children: [] },
            ],
        },
        { val: 6, children: [] },
    ],
};



let ret = 0;
console.log("ret: ", sum([tree])); //get 21 this case
```

...but that hardly counts as an "optimization".

Comment: This is quite memory intensive, each newly created array passed as argument being referenced from the call stack until the end. Recreating arrays at every call costs time too.

Answer (score 1):

Most JavaScript engines do not currently implement tail call optimisation, but if you really want a tail call, and it must be depth-first order, then you will need to mimic the iterative algorithm, and pass a stack reference to the tail call.

Here is a recursive function with a tail call that performs a pre-order traversal. It uses the stack to keep track of the current indices in each of the unfinished `children` arrays.

```js
const preorder = ({val, children}, stack=[], sum=0) => {
    let i = 0;
    if (!children?.length) {
        if (!stack.length) return sum + val; // Last value in preorder sequence
        [children, i] = stack.splice(-2); // Get next sibling: children[i]
    }
    if (i + 1 < children?.length) stack.push(children, i + 1);
    return preorder(children[i], stack, sum + val);
}


// Example tree
const tree = {val: 1,children: [{ val: 2, children: [] },{val: 3,children: [{ val: 4, children: [] },{ val: 5, children: [] },],},{ val: 6, children: [] },],};
console.log(preorder(tree));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use reduce method and arrow function to optimize.

```js
function dfs(root) {
   return root.val + root.children.reduce((sum, child) => sum + dfs(child), 0);
}
```

Comment: Definitely cleaner, but not a tail call (or really an optimization).